# How to set the registration point in the Flash CS6 Spritesheet export function?

Tags: flash, position, export, sprite-sheet, flash-cs6

I am trying to adjust the **Spritesheet** exported JSON file so I can import the sprites with their position at their **registration point**.

In Flash I just add the **offset** which is `frame.offsetInSource` to the **position** but that doesn't works... This is how I export it now:

```
function frameExport(frame)
{

var s;
if (hitFrame)
    s = "\n,{\n";
else
    s = "\n{\n";
s += AddKeyRect("frame", frame.frame);
s+= ",\n";
var spriteSourceSize = new Object();
spriteSourceSize.x = frame.offsetInSource.x;
spriteSourceSize.y = frame.offsetInSource.y;
spriteSourceSize.w = frame.sourceSize.w;
spriteSourceSize.h = frame.sourceSize.h;
s += AddKeyRect("offset", spriteSourceSize);
s += "}";

hitFrame = true;

return s;
 }
```

How can I export this the good way, so their **relative** position is also exported as an **offset variable**?
And are there also other variables you can use for this? 
I know you can use these variables:

```
frame.frame.x
frame.frame.y
frame.frame.w
frame.frame.h
frame.offsetInSource.x
frame.offsetInSource.y
frame.sourceSize.w
frame.sourceSize.h
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 3):

I also tried to use Sprite Sheet Exporter to export the relative position of each frame. But I found, that in the metadata, the value of "frame.offsetInSource.x" is always zero. I guess that would be what I want, and what you want.

I tried to edit the JSON.plugin.jsfl, uncomment the traces. And sadly it's still zero.

Till now, I haven't figured it out why.

Comment: Yes I got the same problem, so I kind of skipped it.